# Fullcalendar.io How to intercept 'prev' and 'next' from the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm building an app using react with typescript and now for displaying a calendar I'm using [Fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/)
My problem is that I don't know how to intercept the event when you click on the header `prev` or `next` as you can see into the attached pic.
The provided solution form the library is [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-prev). But I want to know if I can use another smart solution.

[image: Portion of code]

Thanks in advice.

Comment: I'm afraid that if nothing is talking about any callback on these event in the documentation of the plugin, it would be impossible except you write it on your own.

Comment: The first question would be to go back a step and ask why you want to do this? if you are using it simply to know when to load events onto the calendar, then that's the wrong approach - instead you should declare a dynamic event source (there are a couple of ways to do that depending on your circumstances, documented [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

Comment: P.S. [calendar-prev](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-prev) is a way to **trigger** that event, not a way to intercept it. There is no direct way to intercept the pressing of those buttons, because it's not expected that you will need it. Almost always, there is another way to achieve your goal, if you explain to us what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bump this if I may (apologies if this is not allowed).

I have a similar requirement, to intercept the call to calendar.next(), or at least when the buttons are pressed (as I have no other call to the functions).

My requirement is due to a legal requirement that means I have to have text on my page be bilingual. As Welsh is not a supported locale option, I have to manually adjust the text.

I've had to do similar with Moment.js text, so piggybacking on the function I wrote for that (simple replace text function).

```
if (userData.languagePref > 1) {
    var calMonthText = $('.fc-left h2').text();

    var translatedText = translateMomentJsFromNowText(calMonthText);
    $('.fc-left h2').text(translatedText);
}
```

This is called after the calendar is initialised, and works on the initial display, however I need to run this when the next/prev buttons are used as well.